# CloudFormation SNS - how to pass custom values

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-sns

I'm trying to pass an output value of a resource (such as a DNS name) to the SNS notification payload which is received by a lambda I have set up. This does not seem possible.

For example, in the incoming event for the lambda (which is subscribed to the SNS stack notifications) looks about like this

```
ResourceStatus='CREATE_COMPLETE'
ResourceProperties='{....}'
ResourceStatusReason=''
ResourceType='AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::LoadBalancer'
StackName='test'
...
```

But I would like to pass more information to this payload. I tried adding to the Outputs of the stack template, but it did not change this notification payload. Is there a way to customize this?

Comment: I don't know about the notification, but if you have the stack name, you can use CloudFormation API to get the resources/outputs manually.

Comment: Thanks, I figure thats by backup strategy, just seems more indirect but I'll go with that if there is no other option.